# Ransack + Dropdown not working after sorting

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

The dropdown list and sort by price worked for the first time I clicked it. Once it finished sorting, the dropdown list is not functioning anymore. ie: it doesn't fire up the list.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter :
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><%= sort_link @search, :price, "Price" %></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have searched thoroughly in Stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer for it. Does anybody has any idea about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `sort_link` helper is designed to be used in drop downs. If you check out the [docs](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search#sorting-columns) it's for sorting tables by a specific column.

You can check out the implementation [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search/blob/c7f084412c483456830b8ec26514991e17da94c7/lib/meta_search/helpers/url_helper.rb).